# Custom Service run on local agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using VSTS online with some on-prem build agents. I need to populate a build task GUI picklist with the results of on-prem REST services which are not and won't be publicliy accessible. Is this possible? It seems that custom services always run on the public VSTS server and so can't get data from non-public services? This seems like a major architectural issue for an enterprise using VSTS in the cloud.

Comment: Build definitions are generally static, so I have to ask the question: What is this information that is getting pulled from your on-prem services to populate a picklist? And why is it changing so frequently that it needs to be live-queried from a service?

Comment: What do you mean non-public services? And the following links may help: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/667 and 
 https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/801

Comment: For example, I need to populate picklists with server/db instance names which can be selected as the target for what the task does. There are a lot of such servers/dbs and more can be added at any time and so I have to retrieve the list from a REST call. I have the REST call and the db behind this already but need to be able to query it as part of the task GUI. By "non-public" I mean behind a corporate firewall, accessible to our on-prem build agents but not to the cloud VSTS servers.

Comment: Those two links don't really address what I am asking - they are cases where they are using (or told to use) on-prem VSTS which would be no problem for us either but we have cloud VSTS.